# Why is Django admin giving me TemplateDoesNotExist Error

Tags: django, django-admin, admin

Using Django==3.1, when I try and go to the admin pages, I'm getting the error

`raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)   admin/apidocs_index.html`

I never used to get this happening.

my urls:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('copo/', include('web.apps.web_copo.urls', namespace='copo')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('rest/', include('web.apps.web_copo.rest_urls', namespace='rest')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('accounts/profile/', views.index),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name='index')
]
```

and template settings

```
TEMPLATES = [

{

    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here

        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web', 'landing'),
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web', 'apps', 'web_copo', 'templates', 'copo'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            # processor for base page status template tags
            "web.apps.web_copo.context_processors.get_status",
            "web.apps.web_copo.context_processors.add_partial_submissions_to_context",

            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        ],
        'debug': True,
    },
},
```

]

I don't have any more details to add at this time

Comment: Where did you store your template? What is the path *relative* to the project root?

Comment: Which template?

Comment: The `admin/api_docs.html`.

Comment: it should just be directing to the standard django admin templates. I don't know why its trying to load this api_docs.html.